# Java: Why separate class must be private

Tags: java, oop

For example I have a file name call "A.java". Here its structure:

```
public class A{
}

private class B{
   // no error
}
public class C{
   //error : must declare at different file
}
```

I think this is Java rules. But, I really want to know: WHY java need to do that.

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by separate? I'm confused..

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826685/source-file-cant-have-more-than-one-public-class

Comment: Are you sure class B isn't an inner class of class A (typo/badly closed backet perhaps)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class A{
}

private class B{
   // no error
}
```

This shouldn't even work ([see Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6)):

> It is a compile-time error if a top level type declaration contains
>   any one of the following access modifiers: protected, private, or
>   static

Are you sure you haven't declared class `B` as an inner class?

It doesn't make sens to declare a top-level class as `private`, since private restricts the visibility of members to the enclosing top-level class/interface. If your class is a top-level class (whether or not in its own file), you'd at least want package-level visibility (no modifier at all).

Comment: Works for me! You can have only one *public* class and it must have the same name as the file, but as many private and default (package-level) classes of any name as you like in the same file.

Comment: @Bohemian, which compiler are you using? It doesn't work with OpenJDK 6's `javac`. (Default/package-level works, but that's not forbidden by the spec as far as I can tell.)

Comment: @Bruno No. It works. Just not true for public. I'm using JDK 7. But I don't think it depend on Sun or OpenSource

Comment: @hqt, I'm merely quoting the spec. Doesn't work for me with Oracle JDK 7's `javac` or with Eclipse compiler either. As I said, private for a top-level class doesn't make sense anyway

Answer (score 3):

You can find in section 7.6 of the JLS:

> When packages are stored in a file system (§7.2.1), the host system
>   may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error
>   if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type
>   name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the
>   following is true:
>
> The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the
>   package in which the type is declared. The type is declared public
>   (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages).
>   This restriction implies that there must be at most one such type per
>   compilation unit. This restriction makes it easy for a compiler for
>   the Java programming language or an implementation of the Java virtual
>   machine to find a named class within a package; for example, the
>   source code for a public type wet.sprocket.Toad would be found in a
>   file Toad.java in the directory wet/sprocket, and the corresponding
>   object code would be found in the file Toad.class in the same
>   directory.

Answer (score 1):

There can only be one public class per .java file, as public classes must have the same name as the source file.

From your example: if you have file "A.java", only class A can be public.

Answer (score 1):

It is defined in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/j3TOC.html).

Comment: Does a link to the entire JLS really help?

Answer (score 0):

well,

you cannot have structure is a file called 'A.java' because you intended public class is named 'ClassA', then the file name must be ClassA.java. Now, as far as I understand, the idea behind this restriction is just to be organized. So you can have the physical origin of every class.

Without this restriction u can have a for example 'ClassC' coming from 'nowhere', and it could be really difficult to track the source code.

regards

Comment: I think there were spaces missing in the question (I've edited it to add them). `public classA` -> `public class A`.