# multiple public classes in java

Tags: java

I was trying to write a Java program with more than 1 public class and it gave me the following error:

```
Class [classname] is public,should be declared in a separate file named 
[classname].java
```

Can't seem to find a convincing answer as to why this is happening.

Comment: Isn't *"should be declared in a separate file named [classname].java"* clear ?

Comment: The correct remedy to the error is given in the error message, so it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Just follow the message!

Comment: thanks guys i found my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578490/why-only-1-public-class-in-java-file?rq=1

Comment: @ParthMody I hope you meant **"Because he said so!!"**.

Comment: @dystroy:No,absolutely not!Read the first answer,it makes perfect sense!He said so,for a reason!

Answer (score 3):

You can not declare more than one public class in one `.java` file. Separate your classes to different `.java` files.

**Class1.java**

```
public class Class1 {

}
```

**Class2.java**

```
public class Class2 {

}
```

---

> This restriction implies that there must be at most one such type per
>   compilation unit. This restriction makes it easy for a compiler for
>   the Java programming language or an implementation of the Java virtual
>   machine to find a named class within a package; for example, the
>   source code for a public type wet.sprocket.Toad would be found in a
>   file Toad.java in the directory wet/sprocket, and the corresponding
>   object code would be found in the file Toad.class in the same
>   directory.

### Similar questions:

- [Why only 1 public class in Java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578490/why-only-1-public-class-in-java-file)
- [source file can't have more than one public class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826685/source-file-cant-have-more-than-one-public-class)

Comment: Yes,that's true,but why?

Answer (score 2):

Every public class must be declared in it's own .java source file.

Answer (score 2):

The class name is the same as the file name. If you have more than one class in a file, it creates a conflict which causes errors. So each class should be in a separate file with the file name same as the class name.